# Concatenate strings stored in variables side by side

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two variables which contain a set of strings. I need to concatenate the results of these variables to appear side by side.

Variable `a` has:

```
t
t
t
```

Variable `b` has:

```
xyz
pqr
stu
```

I need to get the output as

```
txyz
tpqr
tstu
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use same letter on multiple lines ? Why not have VAR='t' instead ?

Comment: I need 3 words starting with t

Comment: @praveen_reddy  but just appending single character to the begging of each work is enough. Same as what muru showed in his answer.  I can post a few other alternative approaches, but I just don't understand the purpose of having 3 `t` when only one can be used to achieve the same goal

Answer (score 7):

On bash, you can do this with process substitution and `paste`:

```
$ a='t                                 
t
t'
$ b='xyz                               
pqr
stu'
$ paste <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b") -d ''
txyz
tpqr
tstu
```

If all you want is `t` prefixed to the lines of `b`, `awk` or `sed` would do:

```
$ printf "%s" "$b" | awk '{printf "t"}1'
txyz
tpqr
tstu
```

Comment: To simply prefix each line of `$b` with character `t`, you could simplify that to `printf "t%s\n" $b` (note the *un*quoted `$b`, so it expands to an IFS separated list)

Answer (score 5):

Using `paste` with process substitution:

```
paste -d '' <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b")
```

- `<()` is process substitution pattern, the output of the command inside will be replaced by a file descriptor, this is needed as `paste` takes files as input
- `d ''` sets the delimiter as null, as needed

**Example:**

```
$ echo "$a"
t
t
t

$ echo "$b"
xyz
pqr
stu

$ paste -d '' <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b")
txyz
tpqr
tstu
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error near '('

Comment: @praveenreddy Perhaps you are using `dash` (`sh` in Ubuntu), use `bash`....

Comment: I  use only bash. @heemayl

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how it compares for efficiency, but a possible pure bash solution might be

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 x; IFS= read -r -u4 y; do 
  printf '%s%s\n' "$x" "$y"; 
done 3<<<"$a" 4<<<"$b"
```

Comment: This processes every line from `$b` and then stops.  If `$a` has more lines, the excess are discarded.  To stop after the end of the shorter variable, do `read` … **`&& `** `read` ….  To read to the end of the longer one (as the `paste` solution does) would be trickier.

Answer (score 2):

If all you really want is 3 words starting with `t` , you can do this:

```
$ echo $VAR_2 | awk '{print "t"$0}'                                             
txyz
tpqr
tstu
```

Or this:

```
$ echo $VAR_2 | sed 's/^/t/g'                                                   
txyz
tpqr
tstu
```

If you have multiple (and different) words in variables, they don't lend themselves nicely for simultaneous processing, so I would suggest using `array` instead of variables.

```
$ array1=( 't' 't' 't'  )                                                       


$ array2=('xyz' 'pqr' 'stu' )


$ for i in $(seq 0 2) ; do echo "${array1[$i]}""${array2[$i]}" ; done
txyz
tpqr
tstu
```